# extract string using regex?

Tags: regex

```
Sample Data:

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|refererurl                                                                       |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|https://www.tesco.com/groceries/dfp/dfp-beaa1a3b14.html                          |
|https://www.tesco.com/groceries/dfp/dfp-beaa1a3b14.html                          |
|https://www.tesco.com/groceries/dfp/dfp-beaa1a3b14.html                          |
|https://www.tesco.com/groceries/dfp/dfp-beaa1a3b14.html                          |
|http://mbappgiwwg33nfz2gk43dn4xgo4tpmnsxe6joozuwk5y8.com/                        |
|http://mbappgewtgobzgu4dcmrtgy888888.com/                                        |
|https://www.tesco.com/groceries/dfp/dfp-beaa1a3b14.html                          |
|http://mbappgiwwg33nfz2gk43dn4xgo4tpmnsxe6joozuwk5y8.com/                        |
|https://www.tesco.com/groceries/dfp/dfp-beaa1a3b14.html                          |
|https://www.tesco.com/groceries/dfp/dfp-beaa1a3b14.html                          |
|null                        |
|https://www.tesco.com/groceries/dfp/dfp-beaa1a3b14.html                          |
|http://mbappgiwwg33nfz2gk43dn4xgo4tpmnsxe6joozuwk5y8.com/                        |
|https://www.tesco.com/groceries/dfp/dfp-beaa1a3b14.html                          |
|http://mbappgiwwg33nfz2gk43dn4xgo4tpmnsxe6joozuwk5y8.com/                        |
|https://www.tesco.com/direct/party-gifts-flowers/helium-canisters/cat31450037.cat|
|https://www.tesco.com/groceries/dfp/dfp-beaa1a3b14.html                          |
|https://www.tesco.com/groceries/dfp/dfp-beaa1a3b14.html                          |
|https://www.tesco.com/groceries/dfp/dfp-beaa1a3b14.html                          |
|https://www.tesco.com/groceries/dfp/dfp-beaa1a3b14.html                          |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want regex expression as follows:

a. I want a regex expression which can start extracting backward before '.com' till website name including .com 
for eg.
 
https://www.tesco.com/groceries/dfp/dfp-beaa1a3b14.html --> tesco.com
http://mbappgiwwg33nfz2gk43dn4xgo4tpmnsxe6joozuwk5y8.com --> mbappgiwwg33nfz2gk43dn4xgo4tpmnsxe6joozuwk5y8.com

Comment: So what regex did you come up with?

Comment: please show us what you have tried already.

Comment: \/\/(.*)(?<=.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex seems to work here:

```
[^.\/]+.com
```

### Demo

Note that this doesn't consider possible URLs like `tesco.co.uk.com`, in which case we would need to do more work.

Comment: some websites also have special characters like hyphen e.g
te-sco.com.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/(?:www.)?)(.*?)\/
```

It should work even with url like:
www.example.co.uk/qsdqsd.html

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/DLiqbr/1)

Comment: This pattern doesn't work for me, and also it would capture the `www` portion of the URL, which the OP does not want.